# Получение ответа от QProcess

Tags: c++, qt

Необходимо запустить дочерний процесс, вводить и выводить данные из него последовательно. Однако, если дочерний процесс имеет цикл ввода, получить от него данные не удается. Код запуска процесса и соединения со слотом:

```
   RSGui::RSGui(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), rsgCommandBuilder(CommandBuilder::getInstance())
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    rsgProcess = new QProcess();
    connect(rsgProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(printOutput()));
    rsgProcess->start("C://infinityLoop");
    rsgProcess->waitForStarted(-1);
    rsgProcess->write("1");
    rsgProcess->write("2");
    rsgProcess->write("8");
    rsgProcess->closeWriteChannel();
    rsgProcess->waitForFinished();
    rsgProcess->kill();
}
void RSGui::printOutput()
{
    qDebug() << "call";
    ui.plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(rsgProcess->readAllStandardOutput());
}
```

Запускаемый дочерний процесс (infinityLoop.exe):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i != 8)
    {
        cin >> i;
        cout << "Entered: " << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод qDebug() не понятен, много раз обращается к слоту:
[image: Вывод qDebug()]

Comment: Вы возможно хотели спросить: "как ввод передать дочернему процессу в Qt" (ввод проще: вы контролируете буфер. С выводом сложнее: если дочерний процесс записал ответ в буфер стандартного вывода, то снаружи тяжело до него добраться может, пока он не заполнится или при выходе из программы не будет очищен. В вашем случае `endl` очищает (flush) буфер, поэтому вы должны увидеть ответ (одну строку, но процесс живой), после  `closeWriteChannel()` (не раньше, так как пробелов во вводе для cin у вас нет) См. [Python C program subprocess hangs at "for line in iter"](https://goo.gl/UO2DhL))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько `call` в выводе можно объяснить тем, что в дочернем процессе вы не проверяете EOF, поэтому после `.closeWriteChannel();` вызова второй и последующие `cin >> i` сразу же с ошибкой возвращаются, позволяя циклу несколько итераций совершить в дочернем процессе.

Если добавить проверку на EOF в дочерний цикл:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  for(int i; std::cin >> i && i != 8; )
    std::cout << "Entered: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

тогда вы должны увидеть `call` только раз.

---

`.write("1"); .write("2"); .write("8");` в вашем случае равнозначны одному `.write("128");` -- канал (pipe) принимает байты (это поток байт, а не сообщений). В родителе может быть исходящий буфер, в дочернем процессе может быть входящий буфер, плюс `cin >> i` ждёт или пробела или EOF/ошибки, то есть в вашем случае пока `.closeWriteChannel();` не вызван cin не возвращается. Вы вероятно хотели: `.write("1 2 8")` написать.

---

`waitForStarted()`, `waitForFinished()` могут заморозить ваше GUI (["Calling this function from the main (GUI) thread might cause your user interface to freeze."](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished)). Вы можете вместо этого подключить соответствующие сигналы. К примеру, используя qt5 синтаксис для сигналов и c++11 lambda:

```
QProcess p;
p.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels); // merge child's stdout/stderr

// process started; write some input to the child process
QObject::connect(&p, &QProcess::started, [&]() {
    QTextStream stream {&p};
    for (int i : {1, 2, 8}) stream << i << " ";
    stream.flush();
    p.closeWriteChannel(); // no more input
  });

// process' output is ready
QObject::connect(&p, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&]() {
    qDebug() << "<" << p.readAllStandardOutput() << ">";
  });

// process finished
QObject::connect(&p, static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),    //XXX use qOverload<> in Qt5.7+
                 [&](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus) {
                   qDebug() << "finished with " << exitCode;
                 });
//XXX use connect(&p, &QProcess::errorOccurred,..
p.start("./child"); //XXX *nix
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, для корректной записи в поток ввода дочернего процесса, необходимо было добавлять символ переноса строки в конце записи '\n', так как аргумент метода write() - это const char *data, который не заботится о его наличии. [О потоке ввода cin](https://cppstudy.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/cin-get-and-co/).

Пример рабочего кода:

```
rsgProcess->write("1\n");
rsgProcess->write("2\n");
rsgProcess->write("8\n");
```

Вывод в plainTextEdit:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]